# Как открыть изображения в БД c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Имеется приложение, которое работает как клиентское для БД (Access). В БД имеется ряд изображений, которые хранятся как гиперссылки (например, D:\Database\Image1.png). Изображения хранятся на сетевом диске.
При запросе данные выводятся в dataGridView посредством oledb:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       OleDbDataAdapter dataada2 = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Таблица1", oleDbWay);
       DataSet dataset1= new DataSet();
       dataada2 .Fill(dataset1, "Adapt");
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset1.Tables[0];
    }
```

Соответственно при запуске программы в датагридвью появляются ссылки. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы вместо ссылок появлялись сами изображения (если такое возможно).
[SPOILER]Возможно стоит использовать в БД для строк с изображениями тип данных ole? Само поле в таком случае должно идти как ссылка на изображение?[/SPOILER]

Comment: Я правильно понял пример ссылки - изображения хранятся на сервере рядом с БД? Ну тогда сервер и должен прочитать эти файлы и отдать их в результатах запроса. А как именно, зависит от БД, о которой вы ни слова не написали. Если Изображения хранятся на шаре, доступной клиенту, то клиент может и сам их получить, после этого объединить данные запроса и загруженные файлы и отобразить это на гриде. Вопрос необходимо уточнить

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, изменил вопрос. Необходимо, чтобы при выводе на грид ссылки отображались как изображения или же при нажатии на ссылку открывалось изображение.

Comment: Ок, но на один из вопросов вы так и не ответили. У клиентской программы есть прямой доступ к изображениям или нет? БД удаленная или локальная (на той же машине, что и клиент)?

Comment: У dataGridView есть событие "навроди" onRowAnd(), в обработчике которого Вы загружаете файл c  изображением (BitMap), по адресу полученным из базы, и далее "запихиваете" BitMap в специально добавленную ручками в dataGridView колонку нужного типа. Это общая схема, больше сейчас Вам ничем помочь не могу, если сами не справитесь, то завтра я постараюсь, если будет время, расписать Вам подробнее.

Comment: Да, конечно. И программа, и сами изображения находятся на одном компьютере.